# How to fix the Core Foundation object with a +1 retain count (ARC)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

Here is my method:

```
CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(aSampleBuffer);

CIImage *ciImage = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:imageBuffer];

CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
CGImageRef myImage = [context
                      createCGImage:ciImage
                      fromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0,
                                          CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer),
                                          CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer))];

return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:myImage];
```

But last line show me is `Potential leak of an object stored into 'myimage'`, and the line of myImage is `Method returns a Core Foundation object with a +1 retain count`. But my application is ARC enabled, so I can't `release` something. How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: BTW, "so I can't release something" - read what the warning says. Your object is a CoreFoundation object, you don't `release` it, but `CFRelease` (or, in this case, it has a designated release function), which you call on it. ARC should not forbid that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My application is ARC enabled, so I can't release something

Wrong. ARC prevents you from sending the `release` message to Objective-C objects, since it manages their memory for you.

However you still have to manually manage the memory in any other case (i.e. C structures). You can - and must - use `retain`/`release` functions on such structures whenever appropriate.

In this case you have to manually call `CGImageRelease` on `myImage`, balancing the retain count, by doing (as proposed by H2CO3)

```
    UIImage *retVal = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:myImage];
    CGImageRelease(myImage);
    return retVal;
```

Comment: `UIImage` and `CGImageRef` are *not* toll-free bridged. And there is no `CFImage`. I assume that your second solution will crash.

Comment: @MartinR. Tiring day. you're absolutely right, I'll cut away that part

Comment: @MartinR done. Thank you for pointing out the spectacular error in my answer ;) In my defense, it's a crazy hot day here in Italy!

Answer (score 5):

```
UIImage *retVal = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:myImage];
CGImageRelease(myImage);
return retVal;
```